# Post title not saving

Tags: javascript

I have some custom JavaScript on the admin side, on for counting the posts, the other for checking if a checkbox have been ticked.

```
$('.inside input').on('click', function() { 
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        console.log('checked');
            $('#title').val('overview');
        } else {
            $('#title').val(title);
        }
    });
```

the other one

```
$('#postexcerpt').find('textarea').on('keyup', function(e) {

        max_chars = 240 - $(this).val().length;
        if (max_chars < 1) {

            $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0,238));
        }
        $('#counterbox').html(max_chars);

    });
```

The codes above are working. My problem is when I save the post, CPT or any other post type the Title field does not get saved? Any ideas on this?

Update - Saving CPT

```
add_action('save_post','save_press_meta');
```

function save_press_meta() {
    global $post;
    $post_id = $post->ID;

```
if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;

    if( isset( $_POST['paper'] ) )  
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'paper',$_POST['paper']);

    if( isset( $_POST['press_article_thumbnail'] ) )  
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'articlethumbnail',$_POST['press_article_thumbnail']);

    if( isset( $_POST['press_article_content'] ) )  
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'articlecontent',$_POST['press_article_content']);      

    if( isset( $_POST['press_article_pubtime'] ) )  
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'articlepubtime',$_POST['press_article_pubtime']);
```

}

Comment: Can i look at your code for saving posts

Comment: Code is updated

Comment: Where is this checkbox, and `.inside`, this class is used by WordPress as well for publish button wrapper, your js will conflict.
See if you are getting some js error in console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem lies here,

```
 $('.inside input').on('click', function() { 
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {

            $('#title').val('overview');
        } else {
            $('#title').val(title);
        }
    });
```

".inside input" in your javascript code is checkbox?
If yes then, it will also apply to **publish button.**
So when you click publish button,above js will be called and will change the title.
Use some id or specific class other than ".inside".